# *Concrete* risks of using HTTP GET for requests that have side-effects? (I know the theory.)

Tags: http, fetch-api

I know that, in principle, HTTP GET requests shouldn't have any side-effects (i.e. idempotent).

But I'm experimenting and, so far, my test HTTP GET requests that change data on a test database work just fine: it doesn't look like the HTTP GET requests ever get re-requested.

Now my tests are not representative of the real world. In the real world, any middle-man (e.g. Cloudflare) could take in consideration the fact that the HTTP request is `GET` and re-request the HTTP request, for example upon flaky networking. But I wonder if this actually ever happens?

Note that the HTTP requests in question are all browser-side `fetch()` JSON requests using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). (I think that's relevant because while Cloudflare does re-request HTML resources, I don't think Cloudflare would ever re-request a `fetch()` JSON request.)

My gut feeling says that, while in theory such HTTP GET requests are allowed to be re-requested, it doesn't happen in practice. Am I right or is there a situation showing that I'm wrong?

### Context

I'm the author of [Telefunc](https://telefunc.com/) which is a JavaScript/TypeScript RPC implementation and I'd like to make all Telefunc's HTTP request be `GET`, even when the user makes database changes. I'd like to do this because this would enable Telefunc to support ETag caching for all requests and without the user having to configure anything.

Comment: " it doesn't look like the HTTP GET requests ever get re-requested" - are you sure? When a user selects the URL from the browser history, when a user reloads the page, then the request obviously happens repeatedly

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, but that's expect. The key question is whether the request is re-requested without the user having re-triggered it. I.e. if the request ever gets "duplicated".

Comment: What happens if I close the browser and open it again, with the same set of tabs opened?

Comment: I would think that bigger problem is when the GET request is fulfilled from some kind of server cache, not reaching server application at all? (I don't know, is that possible in your scenario or not.)

Comment: "I wonder if this actually ever happens" - did you check all CDNs for this? Maybe they perform some kind of prefetching or actualization for their cached requests?

Comment: These are good points. Thanks! I'm giving up the idea and I'll keep all Telefunc's HTTP requests to be POST.

Comment: Never mind that if your clients decided to give their internal search appliance the ability to index your application end points. Repeatedly.